Simplification of expression with PolyLog[4,2]
I am trying to simplify the following expression.
expr=1/2 \[Pi]^2 Log[2]^2-2/3 I \[Pi] Log[2]^3-4 PolyLog[4,2]+7/2 Log[2] Zeta[3]

This expr is a real number
expr//N


-4.4243 + 6.66134*10^-16 I

I was wondering whether expr can be brought to a form involving real-valued numbers/functions only.
It might be expressed in terms of transcendental numbers (this is from experience involving multiloop computation in Physics where this expression arises).
Something like
expr= a2*Zeta[2] + a3*Zeta[3] + a4*Zeta[4]+a5

with a1,...,a5 are unknown rational numbers.
I tried to utilize the resource function PolyLogSimplify without any luck:
expr//FunctionExpand
ResourceFunction["PolyLogSimplify"][expr]

Looking into Wolfram resources I did not find much related to PolyLog[4,2] (like simplified identities etc.).
I came to the above form of expr from the expansion of a Hypergeometric2F1 using HypExp
Collect[FunctionExpand@Series[(16 Hypergeometric2F1[alp/2,1/2 (alp-2 eps),(2+alp)/2,-1])/alp,{alp,0,1},{eps,0,2}],{eps,alp},FullSimplify]


16/alp - (alp [Pi]^2)/3 + eps ((2 [Pi]^2)/3 - 4 alp Zeta[3]) +
eps^2 (Zeta[3] +
alp ((7 [Pi]^4)/180 + 1/2 [Pi]^2 Log[2]^2 -
2/3 I [Pi] Log[2]^3 - 4 PolyLog[4, 2] + 7/2 Log[2] Zeta[3]))

Edit:: It is easy to see that the Im[PolyLog[4,2]] = -1/6  I  \[Pi]  Log[2]^3 by looking into expr. What I want to achieve is Re[PolyLog[4,2]] in Analytical form.
The closest I get is to write PolyLog[4,2] in terms of PolyLog[4,1/2] which is real valued:
PolyLog[4,2]=-PolyLog[4, 1/2]+ \[Pi]^4/45 + 1/6 \[Pi]^2 Log[2]^2  - Log[2]^4/24 - 1/6 I \[Pi] Log[2]^3

But I believe it is possible to remove any PolyLog from the right side and write purely in terms of Zetas.
Edit2::
As mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm
PolyLog[4, 1/2] involves an alternating double sum of multiple zeta function.

Cautious way: N@N[expr, 30] /. z_Complex :> Re[z] /; Im[z] == 0.  Incautious way: Chop[N[expr]] or Re[N[expr]].

Another way: expr /. z_ :> Re[z] /; PossibleZeroQ[Im[z]] // N. It gives a warning, though; however, it checks to something like 80 digits, instead of 30 in @Goofy's comment.

I might have given the wrong impression writing expr//N. This is just to show that it is a real-valued number (Imaginary part arises due to usual machineprecision round-off).  What I really want is to write expr in an Analytical form by simplifying PolyLog[4,2] which I believe is possible but dont know how.

Basically from the above expression it is easy to see that: Im[PolyLog[4, 2]] = -1/6  I  \[Pi]  Log[2]^3. I am interested in Re[PolyLog[4, 2]] in the analytical form (not a numerical value 2.42786)

See, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html, formulas (15), (16), (17), "No similar formulas of this type are known for higher orders". When the formula for PolyLog[4, 1/2] is not known, neither is the formula for PolyLog[4, 2].

If you want a user base that has more people with a knowledge of special functions, I'd recommend math.SE or mathoverflow.
